# Boost Python and vectors of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost-python

I've read how to expose normal vectors to python in boost python, but I want to know how to expose and make use of a vector. For instance, I have a vector of shared_ptrs as follows:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<StatusEffect> > Effects;
```

Based on the material for exposing vectors, I should be able to expose this type of class. What I want to know is how can I actually add to it? How do I create instances of `shared_ptr<StatusEffect>` since I don't have access to new, and the shared_ptr can point to multiple derived types making adding a static creation method to each class a little tedious.

Does anyone have some pointers or can suggest how to do this? Finding good example for boost::python for what I want to do has been abit tricky

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
struct A {
    int index;
    static shared_ptr<A> create () { return shared_ptr<A>(new A); }
    std::string   hello  () { return "Just nod if you can hear me!"; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_shared_ptr)
{
    class_<A, shared_ptr<A> >("A",boost::python::init<>())
        .def("create",&A::create )
        .staticmethod("create")
        .def("hello",&A::hello)
        .def_readonly("index",&A::index)
    ;

    boost::python::class_<std::vector<shared_ptr<A>>>("PyVec")
    .def(boost::python::vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<shared_ptr< A>>,true >());

}
```

The argument of ",true" is important!

Comment: I believe this only works for `boost::shared_ptr` and not the `std::`

Comment: The argument of "true" *IS* important - that was the piece of info I was missing, thank you

Comment: It's not obvious from the answer whether this refers to std shared_ptr or boost, particularly given the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

See [Pointers and smart pointers](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/PointersAndSmartPointers) for an example.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question though. I wanted to be able to do it without needing to create

Answer (score 0):

You mention that a creation method (constructor) for each class would be a little tedious, but I think that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can partially bind `boost::shared_ptr<StatusEffect>`, omitting the construction just fine with Boost.Python (use `boost::python::no_init`). To have a similar mechanism with `std::shared_ptr<StatusEffect>` you will **also** need to define a `boost::get_pointer<T>()` free function with `T = std::shared_ptr<U>` [as explained in this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568952/c0x-stdshared-ptr-vs-boostshared-ptr). Here is a sketch of a workable solution:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <memory>
...

namespace boost { 
  template<class T> T* get_pointer(std::shared_ptr<T> p) { return p.get(); } 
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(yourmodule) {

  using namespace boost::python;

  class_<StatusEffect, std::shared_ptr<StatusEffect>, boost::noncopyable>("StatusEffect", no_init);

  class_<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<StatusEffect> > >("StatusEffectVector")
    .def(boost::python::vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<shared_ptr<StatusEffect>>, true>());

}
```